# Bind MemoryFile to a service fails

Tags: android, ipc

I am trying to bind a `Service` to an `Activity`, which on Bind returns a Memory file object created in the `Service`.

The problem is, during the `onServiceConnected()` callback in the activity, I can receive any type of object from the Service class, except the `MEMORYFILE` type object, which was created in the Service class.

The service fails to bind to the activity when there is a MemoryFile object.

The Service class is as below

```
public class RemoteService extends Service {

IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
MemoryFile mFile; 
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if(mFile == null)
        mFile = new MemoryFile("mem", 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mBinder;
}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MemoryFile getMemoryFile() {
           return mFile;
          }
    }
  }
```

And inside the activity, `Onserviceconnected()` callback happens

`public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
       mBounded = true;
       LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
       memoryFile = mLocalBinder.getMemoryFile();
      }`

Comment: `Service#onBind()` returns IBinder, not MemoryFile

Comment: Yes, in my case, it is mBinder; which is a LocalBinder class.

`public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
  public MemoryFile getMemoryFile() {
      return mFile;
     }
 }`

Comment: Here is a full service class

`public class RemoteService extends Service {
 
 IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
 MemoryFile mFile; 
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
   if(mFile == null)
   mFile = new MemoryFile("mem", 1024);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return mBinder;
 }
 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
  public MemoryFile getMemoryFile() {
      return mFile;
     }
 }
}`

Comment: And inside the Activity, when the service is connected.

`public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
    mBounded = true;
    LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
    memoryFile = mLocalBinder.getMemoryFile();
   }`

Comment: dont add long code as a comment, its hard to read it, edit your question instead